# Use R to write multiple sheets in excel with dynamic sheetNames

Tags: r, lapply, r-xlsx

This can easily be done using `for` loop but I am looking for a solution with `lapply` or `dplyr`.

I have multiple dataframes which I want to export to excel file in separate sheets (I saw many questions and answers on similar lines but couldn't find one that addressed naming sheets dynamically).

I want to name the sheet by the name of the dataframe. For simplicity, I have named the dataframes in a pattern (say df1 to df10). How do I do this?

Below is a reproducable example with my attempt with two dataframes `mtcars` and `cars` (which is working, but without good sheetnames).

```
names_of_dfs=c('mtcars','cars') 
# variable 'combined' below will have all dfs separately stored in it
combined = lapply(as.list(names_of_dfs), get)
names(combined)=names_of_dfs # naming the list but unable to use below

multi.export=function(df,filename){
  return(xlsx::write.xlsx(df,file = filename,
                          sheetName = paste0('sheet',sample(c(1:200),1)),
                          append = T))
}

lapply(combined, function(x) multi.export(x,filename='combined.xlsx'))
```

In case it can be done more easily with some other r package then please do suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(xlsx)
#Workbook
wb = createWorkbook()
#Lapply
lapply(names(combined), function(s) {
  sht = createSheet(wb, s)
  addDataFrame(combined[[s]], sht)
})
saveWorkbook(wb, "combined.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. After this answer I realized I don't even need to create list of all my dfs. In `addDataFrame` I used `get(s)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach with `writexl`:

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(setNames(lapply(names_of_dfs,get),names_of_dfs),
           path = "Test.xlsx")
```

We need to use `setNames` because the names of the sheets are set from the list names. Otherwise, the unnamed list that `lapply` returns will result in default sheet names.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `setNames` (I was searching for something like this). Didn't use your solution as I not very familier with this package and I got another answer. But I am sure this also works, so thanks again :)

Comment: This method is more concise.  It simply takes a list from R and export to an Excel file.

Comment: @Steve: I realised this later. I was too lazy to explore a new package and so depended on `xlsx` based answer. But indeed this is neater.